# Stripping strings of left brackets and slashes in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, strip

I need to strip the characters after the third '-', after the first "(", and after the first '/' , and keep the result in a new column, keepcat.

```
        violation_code        violation_description                                 keepcat
ticket_id           
22056   9-1-36(a)             Failure of owner to obtain certificate of compliance  9-1-36
27586   61-63.0600            Failed To Secure Permit For Lawful Use Of Building    61-63.0600
18738   61-63.0500            Failed To Secure Permit For Lawful Use Of Land        61-63.0500
18735   61-63.0100            Noncompliance/Grant Condition/BZA/BSE                 61-63.0100
23812   61-81.0100/32.0066    Open Storage/ Residential/ Vehicles                   61-81.0100/32.0066
26686   61-130.0000/130.0300  Banner/ Signage/ Antenna                              61-130.0000/130.0300
325555  9-1-43(a) - (Structu  Fail to comply with an Emergency                      9-1-43
```

I have managed to delete the dashes ("-") and the brackets ("(") with this:

```
df['keepcat']=df['violation_code'].apply(lambda x: "-".join(x.split("-")[:3]) and x.split('(')[0].strip())
```

however, when I am adding "/" it does not delete the slashes...
I have tried

```
df['violation_code'].apply(lambda x: "-".join(x.split("-")[:3]) and x.split('(')[0].strip())  and x.split('/')[0].strip() )
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you parse the conditions separately:

```
df['keepcat'] = df['violation_code'].apply(lambda x: "-".join(x.split("-")[:3]))
df['keepcat'] = df['keepcat'].apply(lambda x: x.split('(')[0].strip())
df['keepcat'] = df['keepcat'].apply(lambda x: x.split('/')[0].strip())
```

Comment: It does! 
it is grumpy about the loc/copy thing giving 3 warnings but otherwise, it works.  thanku. C:\Users\Maria\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead